# How to read a specific row in a table in Protractor without using XPath?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to write a Protractor test that checks the number inside the `<strong>` tag below:

[image]

I managed to get it working for 1 `<tr>` using `nth-child` below:

```
element(by.css('td:nth-child(4)')).getText().then((text) => {
    console.log('Text', text);
});
```

But if I have multiple rows within the table, it only prints the 1st row.

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make so that I look through each row within the table & print the 4th child?

Comment: from what you pasted, it doesn't look that anything is wrong per se; the test is timing out after 5000ms after waiting for `myValue` to be clickable

Comment: Hi @JoaquinCasco Thanks for your comment. I've updated my code to check `visibilityOf` rather than `elementToBeClickable` & the test is passing now. But I'm getting a different error now, I've updated my code with the issue.

Comment: that's because `visibilityOf` assumes the element is present in the html, that's why it can't find it. You may want to add `presenceOf` before waiting for its visibility/clickability

Comment: So I've updated `visibilityOf` to `presenceOf` & still getting the same error message

Comment: use css `:nth-child()` but sometimes you just can't avoid xpath

Comment: OK, I just thought there'd be some "standard" helper function that would be usable to loop through tables

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov Thanks, I managed to get it working using `nth-child` for 1 row, but not sure how I could loop thrugh multiple rows to print the value within each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `element.all()`

```
element.all(by.css('tr > td:nth-child(4)')).getText().then((texts) => {
    // texts is a string array, includes the 4th column values
    console.log('Text', texts);
});

// or use element.all().each() 
element.all(by.css('tr > td:nth-child(4)')).each((it)=>{
  it.getText().then((text)=>{
    console.log('Text', texts);
  })
});
```